# Calculating coordinate of intersection between lines and circle and degree of line in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Alright, I would call myself a pretty good programmer who never really followed the academic way. Therefor my mathematical knowledge is rather limited, which is a little burden for things I sometimes need to accomplish. I know some of you are pretty clever minds and enjoy calculating this (for you most likely easy) thing:

I need to realize a few diagrams and charts for a customer. I choosed OCanvas as a drawing library. It has really helped and Everything I need to do works fine, but there is one caveat.

I have two circles, and can pass the Objects OCanvas makes for me to a function that draws a line between circle 1's center to the center of circle 2. Now I want to add triangles to the line to make it an arrow.

I know I need to calculate the tilt of the line, to properly align the triangle. I would also need to calculate the position of the intersection between circle border and the line, to position the triangle.

I would provide you some code, but I honestly have no clue on how to calculate this. Known values for me are: Line **startX**, **startY**, **endX**, **endY** as well as circle 1 **X**, **Y** and **radius**/circle 2 **X**, **Y** and **radius** (X and Y represent the center of the circles)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

A visual representation, where the red triangle is needed:

[image]

Comment: i think that my answer now is really close to the solution, just need a little correction on the rotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not complete but it might give you a good start.

```js
let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
  ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
  startX = 50,
  startY = 50,
  endX = 250,
  endY = 150,
  rS = 30,
  rE = 50,
  alpha = Math.atan((startY - endY) / (startX - endX)),
  dir = 0, // start 0 end 1
  side = 10;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(startX, startY, rS, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(endX, endY, rE, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

if (startX < endX) {
 endcx = endX + (rE + side/2) * Math.cos(alpha + Math.PI);
 endcy = endY + (rE + side/2) * Math.sin(alpha + Math.PI);
 startcx = startX - (rS + side/2) * Math.cos(alpha - Math.PI);
 startcy = startY - (rS + side/2) * Math.sin(alpha - Math.PI);
 dir = 0;
} else if (startX >= endX) {
 endcx = endX - (rE + side/2) * Math.cos(alpha + Math.PI);
 endcy = endY - (rE + side/2) * Math.sin(alpha + Math.PI);
 startcx = startX + (rS + side/2) * Math.cos(alpha - Math.PI);
 startcy = startY + (rS + side/2) * Math.sin(alpha - Math.PI);
 dir = 1;
}

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(startcx, startcy);
ctx.lineTo(endcx, endcy);
ctx.lineWidth=3;
ctx.stroke();

drawEqTriangle(ctx, side, startcx, startcy, dir?0:1);
drawEqTriangle(ctx, side, endcx, endcy, dir);

function drawEqTriangle(ctx, side, cx, cy, dir) {
  var h = side * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.translate(cx, cy);
  ctx.rotate(alpha + Math.PI / 2);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  
if (dir === 0) {
  ctx.moveTo(0, -h / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(-side / 2, h / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(side / 2, h / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -h / 2);
} else if (dir === 1) {
  ctx.moveTo(0, h / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(-side / 2, -h / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(side / 2, -h / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(0, h / 2);
}

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ive edited your code to make it also work when startX is bigger than endX. But why is the triangle just a tad off?

Comment: Thanks. Probable because the line itself has a weight.

Comment: Ive tried also switching start and end to make it double sided. Something is not quite right :S Could it be that the axis for the rotation is wrong? Is the code I added even correct lol?

Comment: The coordinates can be pre~evaluated in such a manner that startx and endx will always refer to the left positioned circle :)

Comment: The point is, to be flexible, so no matter where I define start and end, it always sets it correct. Do you see why it is a little off though?

Comment: Your edits.... as I said, I would decide before the drawing moment which one is the left sided circle and which is the other and then keep the formulas correct for that case. There will be 4 cases of study as there are 4 quadrans I, II, III and IV. It is easy matth.

Comment: Yes, you will need to study  all the possible (4) cases though I think will reduce to on;y 2. Do a lil research, don't be lasy :))

Comment: I got it. Thanks man, I will accept this as the answer and edited your answer with the code that matches what I originally asked.

Answer (score 2):

### Render an arrow on a line

If you were using pure canvas it would be a little less fiddly.

First the two circles

```
const circle1 = {
    x : ?,
    y : ?,
    r : ?, // Radius
    lineWidth : ?,
}
const circle2 = {
    x : ?,
    y : ?,
    r : ?,
    lineWidth : ?,
}
```

Then the arrow description

```
const arrow = {
   width : ?,
   depth : ?, // tip to back of arrow head
}
```

The the math.

Get the vector from circle1 to circle2

```
var vx = circle2.x - circle1.x;
var vy = circle2.y - circle1.y;
```

The the distance between them

```
var dist = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
```

You now need to normalise the vector by dividing the vector by the length. This makes the vector one unit long

```
vx /= dist;
vy /= dist;
```

Now you can render the arrow. The tip is one the edge of circle 2. To find that point subtract the radius and half the line width from the distance

```
const aDist = dist - (circle2.r + circle2.lineWidth / 2);
```

The normalised vector can be multiplied by a distance to find the position, or if using the canvas 2D API you use the normal to set the transform and then it is all aligned to the x Axis.

```
ctx.beginPath(); // drawing the arrow head
ctx.lineTo(circle1.x + vx * aDist, circle1.y + vy * aDist); // tip of arrow
```

We need to move back away from the tip and out from the line at 90deg to do this you can rotate a vector 90 deg by swapping the x,y parts and negating the new x.

```
ctx.lineTo(
     circle1.x + vx * (aDist - arrow.depth) - vy * arrow.width, 
     circle1.y + vy * (aDist - arrow.depth) + vx * arrow.width
     //          ^------- along line -----^ ^--Out from line--^ 
);
// and the other side
ctx.lineTo(
     circle1.x + vx * (aDist - arrow.depth) + vy * arrow.width, 
     circle1.y + vy * (aDist - arrow.depth) - vx * arrow.width
     //          ^------- along line -----^ ^--Out from line--^ 
);

// ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Or if you use the transform

```
ctx.setTransform(vx,vy,-vy,vx,circle1.x,circle1.y); // set the circle1 as origin
                                                    // and use the normal to
                                                    // align the x axis
ctx.beginPath(); // drawing the arrow head
ctx.lineTo(aDist,0); // tip of arrow
ctx.lineTo(aDist - arrow.depth, arrow.width);
ctx.lineTo(aDist - arrow.depth, -arrow.width);
// ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restore default transform.
```

#### Example

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");   


const circle1 = {
    x : 50,
    y : 100,
    r : 45, // Radius
    lineWidth : 3,
}
const circle2 = {
    x : 250,
    y : 50,
    r : 45,
    lineWidth : 3,
}
const arrow = {
   width : 10,
   depth : 20, // tip to back of arrow head
}
var vx = circle2.x - circle1.x;
var vy = circle2.y - circle1.y;
var dist = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
vx /= dist;
vy /= dist;
const aDist = dist - (circle2.r + circle2.lineWidth / 2);
ctx.lineWidth = circle1.lineWidth;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(circle1.x, circle1.y, circle1.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(circle2.x + circle2.r, circle2.y);
ctx.arc(circle2.x, circle2.y, circle2.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(circle1.x, circle1.y);
ctx.lineTo(circle2.x, circle2.y);
ctx.stroke();    

ctx.beginPath(); // drawing the arrow head
ctx.lineTo(circle1.x + vx * aDist, circle1.y + vy * aDist); // tip of arrow
ctx.lineTo(
     circle1.x + vx * (aDist - arrow.depth) - vy * arrow.width, 
     circle1.y + vy * (aDist - arrow.depth) + vx * arrow.width
     //          ^------- along line -----^ ^--Out from line--^ 
);
// and the other side
ctx.lineTo(
     circle1.x + vx * (aDist - arrow.depth) + vy * arrow.width, 
     circle1.y + vy * (aDist - arrow.depth) - vx * arrow.width
     //          ^------- along line -----^ ^--Out from line--^ 
);

// ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

```css
canvas { border : 2px solid black; }


const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

#### Example2 using `setTransform`

This uses setTransform to reduce the amount of math. also this example uses the line width to but the arrow head to the circle

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");   


const circle1 = {
    x : 50,
    y : 100,
    r : 45, // Radius
    lineWidth : 3,
}
const circle2 = {
    x : 250,
    y : 50,
    r : 45,
    lineWidth : 3,
}
const arrow = {
   width : 10,
   depth : 20, // tip to back of arrow head
}
var vx = circle2.x - circle1.x;
var vy = circle2.y - circle1.y;
var dist = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
vx /= dist;
vy /= dist;
const aDist = dist - (circle2.r + circle2.lineWidth / 2);
ctx.lineWidth = circle1.lineWidth;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(circle1.x, circle1.y, circle1.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(circle2.x + circle2.r, circle2.y);
ctx.arc(circle2.x, circle2.y, circle2.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(circle1.x, circle1.y);
ctx.lineTo(circle2.x, circle2.y);
ctx.stroke();    

ctx.beginPath(); // drawing the arrow head
ctx.setTransform(vx, vy, -vy, vx, circle1.x, circle1.y); // set the circle1 as origin
                                                    // and use the normal to
                                                    // align the x axis
ctx.beginPath(); // drawing the arrow head
ctx.lineTo(aDist,-circle1.lineWidth/2); // tip of arrow circle1.linewidth is same for line between circles
ctx.lineTo(aDist,circle1.lineWidth/2); // tip of arrow circle1.linewidth is same for line between circles
ctx.lineTo(aDist - arrow.depth, arrow.width + circle1.lineWidth/2);
ctx.lineTo(aDist - arrow.depth, -arrow.width - circle1.lineWidth/2);
// ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restore default transform.
ctx.fill();
```

```css
canvas { border : 2px solid black; }


const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the angle of the tilt for the triangle you need the following:
Assuming `(x1,y1)` are the coordinates of the start of the line, and `(x2,y2)` are the coords of the ending of the line, and you want to draw the triangle at the end of the line:

`alpha = arctan((y2-y2) / (x2-x1))`

Then you need to create the triangle tilted with that angle (alpha).

The other triangle would be `alpha + 180 degrees` or `alpha - 180 degrees` (produce the same).

Comment: Thanks! Will this work no matter if circle1 is left or right to circle2? And how do I get the coordinates to position the circle?

Comment: @DavidFariña I'm sorry, I thought the arrow was pointing to the center of the circle, I'll edit my answer to be more correct. And yes, it should work regardless of the position.

Comment: @DavidFariña Check the edited answer and tag me with results :)

Comment: I have added a visual representation to the original question. I cant test your formulas tight now, but will report back in the evening. Thanks a lot for this, but I'm somehow still missing on where (x,y) position the triangle

Comment: @DavidFariña I re-edited the asnwer, had a mistake. How is the triangle represented? Coords represent the center of it? What are the lengths of its sides? are they equal?

Comment: I'd say 5x5x5 px. The triangle should be positioned that one edge is just touching the outer border of the ellipse. I think i would also need to change the line to go just to the border of the circle, instead of to the center. Otherwise the line might be visible in front of the triangle. However, should I know the position of the triangle, i might easily change the line.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to help you with your problem:

Edit:

By integrating @bluehipy answer, maybe this is going to be closer

```js
//Objects
Circle = function(oX, oY, r){
  this.oX = oX;
  this.oY = oY;
  this.r = r;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(oX, oY, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
}

//Functions
drawArrowFromCirclesOrigins = function(side,c1, c2){
  context.beginPath();
  //line
  context.moveTo(c1.oX, c1.oY);
  context.lineTo(c2.oX, c2.oY);     
  context.stroke();
  //triangle
  var alpha = Math.tan((c2.oY-c1.oY) / (c2.oX-c1.oX));
  var h = side * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2);
  
  context.translate(c2.oX/alpha+c2.r-(-(side/2)), c2.oY/alpha+c2.r-(-(side/2)));
  context.rotate(alpha + Math.PI / 2);

  context.beginPath();

  context.moveTo(0, -h / 2);
  context.lineTo(-side / 2, h / 2);
  context.lineTo(side / 2, h / 2);
  context.lineTo(0, -h / 2);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
  
  context.stroke();
}

//Variables
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Program
var cir1 = new Circle(20, 20, 10);
var cir2 = new Circle(40, 40, 10);
drawArrowFromCirclesOrigins(-11,cir1, cir2);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but this is what I already have. I want the red triangle in my Edit in the original question...

Comment: after move to under //triangle you have to draw the lines and you've done, in this moment i'm not being able to think about a scalable way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Another idea you could use for simplify things (and maybe @Blindman67 implemented above but I don't understand it as such) is to think things like this:

No matter where circles are positioned you can rotate the context in such a way that their centres are on a horizontal, or vertical if you prefer, this way all points of interest are on a single coordinate, linear. Draw what you need and then rotate the context back.

Comment: Actually I already accepted your other answer. Would be good if you could accept my edit, as it is now exactly what i was asking for. Thanks a lot for your help again!